# Непонятная задержка на двух слайдах, при прокрутке назад и вперед(Slick.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Товарищи привет, помогите разобраться! код на CodePen(https://codepen.io/barovskiy777/pen/gOpvdqZ)

Создал слайдер Slick, всем фотографиям слайдера задал прозрачность `opacity:0.3`,
              текущему слайдеру
`.slick-current` задаю `opacity:1;
                       transform:scale(1.5) ;
                       transition: all .7s linear;`

При прокрутке вперед возникает задержка на красном(первом) слайдаре, при прокрутке назад на фиолетовом(последнем).Подскажите из-за чего возникает задержка и можно ли от нее избавится?

Comment: Вот ребята обсуждали как это фиксить: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45405783/slick-slider-css-transition-infinite-loop-bug

Comment: Спасибо, ваша ссылка помогла разобраться.